# Who first proved that we can prove that we prove things we prove?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory

*Sorry about the title, I couldn't resist.*

It's a classic fact that, not only does $PA$ prove every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, but $PA$ *proves* that $PA$ proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence! In particular, restricting attention to $\Sigma_1$ sentences of the form "$PA$ proves ---", in the modal logic of $PA$-provability we have $$\Box(\Box p\implies \Box\Box p).$$

Indeed, even more is true: in the paper [Oracle bites theory](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/310731/preprint324.pdf?sequence=1), Visser states

> It is well known that, in the context of EA, all theories extending
>   the very weak arithmetic R prove all true $\Sigma_1$-sentences.

And various proofs of these facts can be found in various places.

My question is: who first proved (and where) that a strong enough theory of arithmetic proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, and moreover proves that it proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence?

Comment: Motivation: I would like to cite it appropriately in [my answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076800/proofs-of-consistency-for-two-formal-systems/2076825#2076825), since it's a simultaneously useful and subtle enough point that it deserves a good citation IMO.

Comment: Is this something worthy of the "historical overview" tag?

Comment: Isn't the claim that PA proves that PA proves true $\Sigma_1$ statements an instance intead of the modal assertion $\Box(p\implies\Box p)$, where we think of $p$ as representing any $\Sigma_1$ assertion?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, that's the more general version, but that requires us to restrict attention to $p$ which are $\Sigma_1$. In the version I wrote, your "$p$" is my "$\Box p$" - the point being that regardless of what $p$ is, $\Box p$ is always $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't know there *was* an "historical overview" tag in the first place :P. Glancing at questions tagged with it, many or most of them "feel broader" to me. That said, there are definitely some that are as specific as this one. I won't add the tag, but I have no objection if someone else does.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I should clarify that I'm specifically interested in provability statements, which is why I expressed that particular form.

Comment: Let me live neath your spell 
Do do that voodoo that you do so well

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Do_Something_to_Me

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not proud to say that my mind went instead to "Shoop" http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/saltnpepa/shoop.html

Comment: I have always heard the theorem $\Box P \Rightarrow \Box\Box P$ referred to as one of the Hilbert-Bernays, or Hilbert-Bernays-Löb [provability conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_provability_conditions).  In his books *The Logic of Provability* (1995), chapter 2, G. Boolos writes that "Hilbert and Bernays had listed three somewhat ungainly conditions \[…\]. The isolation of (the attractive) (i), (ii), and (iii) \[essentially as on Wikipedia\] is due to Löb."

Comment: It scans better (and seems more accurate) if in the title "things" is replaced by "some things".  Gerhard "Might Even Prove It Too" Paseman, 2016.12.30.

Comment: @ToddTrimble sorry, this comment is better than my first reply to you...My familiarity with the phrase is entirely based on the movie Blazing Saddles. He changes the first occurrence of  Do to Go. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jS_Shu8y0sI

Comment: Can I just say that I love everything about this comment thread? :)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Actually, it's true as written: the point is that "proving a thing" is a $\Sigma_1$ fact, regardless of what the thing is. See my reply to Joel above.

Comment: @WillJagy That was awesomely delivered. Gotta love Harvey Korman.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, I'll check it out. Now R is not finitely axiomatizable, but there are finitely axiomatizable theories (e.g. Q) that also prove every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence; is this also treated in TMR? (I'm interested in these because the existence of such [lets me get rid of an annoying additional condition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080776/two-theories-proving-each-others-consistency-take-2/2080938#2080938) in a certain argument.)

Comment: "(...) $PA$ proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence (...)". What is a **true** sentence?? I imagine "$\phi$ is a true sentence" is a piece of jargon that logicians use to mean something like "$T \vdash\phi$ where $T$ is $ZFC$ or any standard theory that usually people assume as metatheory". Is it correct?

Comment: @Qfwfq You can do that if you like, but there's no reason we can't be Platonists here, too: if we believe in an actual $\mathbb{N}$ (I go back and forth on this), then "true" is perfectly meaningful.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Awesome! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'm not a platonist, so I think I'll stick to the metatheory reading of "true"  :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber After checking it closely, it seems I misremembered the content of the book. While it contains a lot of results on incompleteness/undecidability and on the theories $R$ and $Q$, it does not, actually, include the property of $\Sigma_1$-completeness (they rather show directly that the theories in question can represent all recursive functions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The theorem $\Box P \Rightarrow \Box\Box P$ is due to Martin Löb and first appears in his [1955 paper "Solution of a Problem of Leon Henkin"](http://www.math.umd.edu/~laskow/Pubs/713/Lob.pdf), *J. Symb. Logic* **20** 115–118: it appears as condition (V) (page 116) in the paper in question, and whereas conditions (I)–(IV) are referred there to the earlier (1939) book by Hilbert and Bernays, *Grundlagen der Mathematik*, condition (V) (although easily deduced from the others) is new.

The reasoning "that a strong enough theory of arithmetic proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence" is exactly the one which Löb uses in his proof (if we grant that "$\exists x.(f(x)=0)$" for a recursive $f$ qualifies as "every $\Sigma_1$ sentence").

As evidence that Löb was the first to state this fact, I offer the following quote from G. Boolos in *The Logic of Provability* (1995), chapter 2: "Hilbert and Bernays had listed three somewhat ungainly conditions […]. The isolation of (the attractive) (i), (ii), and (iii) [essentially as [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_provability_conditions)] is due to Löb."  As well as [the entry "Provability Logic"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/) from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: "In the same paper, Löb formulated three conditions on the provability predicate of Peano Arithmetic, that form a useful modification of the complicated conditions that Hilbert and Bernays introduced in 1939 for their proof of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem [again the same conditions as on Wikipedia]".

Answer (score 7):

<del>Both results are due to Feferman.</del> They appear as Lemma 3.10 and Corollary 5.5 of Arithmetization of metamathematics in a general setting, Fundamenta Mathematicae 49:35-92, 1960.

Comment: I'd expect an earlier date:  that paper's introduction says "in general the material in sections 2-4 is quite familiar".

Comment: I think Lob currently has my vote based on Gro-Tsen's answer, but +1: I'm pleased to know about that paper by Feferman!